# Why are Pandas Documentation Pages being Flagged as Unsafe by Google Search?

Tags: pandas, google-chrome, google-search, code-documentation, safe-browsing

[Pandas Warning Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXGtN.png)

[Pandas Warning Detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ou9FD.png)

Some pages from Pandas' official docs are being flagged as Unsafe by Google.

Comment: I'm getting same - have not checked dates on my CERTs...